# Save excel file to PDF with the correct sizing

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, pdf-generation, cell

I am trying to save an Excel file as a PDF for printing purposes. I have set the column width and row height in cm, as I want to print at a specific size (it's a file of name tags that have to fit the tags themselves).
However, when I convert to PDF, they come out at the wrong size, slightly smaller than I have set in the excel (8.5 cm comes out as 7 cm). The same thing happens if I print directly from Excel as well.
How do I get Excel to save to PDF or print at the actual size I have put in?

Comment: Both printer and printer options are defined as A4, so it isn't that...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your Excel is scaling to fit? Go to page layout on the top ribbon and in the "width" and "height" drop downs of the scale to fit section, change these to "automatic". For me, Excel had automatically set to 1 page for each, meaning that Excel tries to scale them down to fit a page. However, keep in mind that this will make Excel print to multiple pages.

Otherwise, there is also a [suggestion from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/214394) here to change the styling (added and slightly modified as mine didn't follow this entirely):

Change the font of the Normal style to match the font used in the worksheet:

1. Press CTRL+A to select all columns and rows in the workbook.
2. On the Format menu, click Style. (is "cell styles" in my Excel and this appears in the home section of the ribbon)
3. In the Style name list, click Normal. Then, right click Modify.
4. On the Font tab, select the correct font (whatever font you are using in the workbook).
5. Click OK twice.